# JSON schema, check if sum of values exceeds 100

Tags: python, json, jsonschema, python-jsonschema

i am writing a `json` schema, that validates files based on the sum of numbers, stored in a property of an `object`, e.g. example below. The Sum of A and B can not exceed 100%. Is there a schema/function that allows this kind of specification?

Thanks in advance

```
"blend": [
        {
            "name": "A",
            "amount": {
                "value": 10.0,
                "unit": "%"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "B",
            "amount": {
                "value": 90.0,
                "unit": "%"
            }
        }
    ]
```

Comment: Not as part of the standard JSON schema specification.

Comment: In a word, no. This goes into "business logic" as apposed to format validation.